# Is it possible to collect all RSSI values for the wifi client(connected devices) from AP'S

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to collect periodically the RSSI values of all connected devices in a certain Wi-fi area which I will use them in my application to monitor the Wi-Fi area. I am asking. 
Is it possible to collect them from my PC using any programming language?
I have searched about this but unfortunately, I didn't get any clear answer. I want to start my master thesis based on this idea if it possible.

that what I have got until now.

1-  API:The product  provides API (Restful API) which retrieve the information                              as  XML or JSON(e.g. Cisco)

2-  SSH/ Telnet and SNMP: to access the file on WLAN (not sure if all information we need  is stored in a specific file) however, still one of the methods to access to WLAN router.

3-  UI web, Which can retrieve the information by creating Get HTTP request and then the response as HTML text contains the information(some model).

4-  There is a Wireless controller device which can provide the RSSI values.

I am not sure if it possible to retrieve all the RSSI or not 
if it possible please give me a hint how to start.

I hope you are able to help me.
thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard that requires an AP to make available, via any API or protocol, the RSSI values for the connected clients. There's also no rule against it, so vendors may have come up with ways to make those values accessible in various ways on various products.

Looking around, it looks like any AP that uses a Broadcom Wi-Fi chipset and can run DD-WRT would allow you to SSH in and use the Broadcom `wl` command to get that kind of information; `wl assoclist`, parse it for MAC addresses, then `wl rssi $MACADDR`.

It looks like Ubiquiti UniFi products can be scripted via [this unifi-api Python package](https://github.com/unifi-hackers/unifi-api).

There are probably other solutions for other devices as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, Really, it is helpful, Sorry , I also have a question: is it possible also to read  all probe response for an access point

Comment: @Moh.Qaid Same answer as above. There's no standard for reading this from the APs, but you may be able to find a way to do it on a particular make/model of AP. If I wanted to see all Probe Response frames an AP is transmitting, I'd just run Wireshark in 802.11 Monitor Mode on a laptop with a high-end Wi-Fi card near the AP.